# Func conversion

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, func

I have a function which receives `Func<T,string>` as a parameter and I'm trying to do an overload with `Func<T,MvcHtmlString>`

The object I am currently sending  is `Html.Partial("MyPartialPath", MyModel).ToString()`
and I want to call that method without redundant `.ToString()` extension

So, this is the original method :

```
   public void Whatever(Func<T, string> partial)
    {
        this.myProperty= partial;
    }
```

And I'm trying to create something like this:

```
   public void Whatever(Func<T, MvcHtmlString> partial)
    {
        this.myProperty= partial; // here fails because myProperty is of type Func<TRow, string>
    }
```

I want to `convert` a `Func<T,MvcHtmlString>` to `Func<T,string>`.

Here is what I've tried

`Func<TRow, string> test= t => partial.ToString();` // it's not working as expected ( doesn't have the same results as the original method )

Is this the correct way to convert, and the error is elsewhere, or I'm not doing the conversion as I should ?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't have the same results as the original method"?

Comment: Doesn't gives me the content of the partial view. It returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick shot I'd say you have a mistake here:

```
Func test= t => partial.ToString();
```

since it references the method `partial` instead of its result.
I think what you probably meant/wanted was:

```
Func test= t => partial(t).ToString();
```

BTW: If `MvcHtmlString` would derive from String, your code would work, since the result type is covariant. But unfortunately this is actually not the case, it was just my 2 cents as a side note.